# Python Syntax Error

Tags: python, printing, syntax-error, pyscripter

I'm on Windows and I'm using PyScripter. For some reason everything results in a syntax error, even code that very obviously does not have a syntax error. For example,

```
print 6
```

gets a syntax error, as does,

```
a = 6
print a

list = (1, 2, 7, 3)
print list

print 3 + 3
```

or any other code I can think of that involves printing. Did I download Python wrong, am I setting it up wrong, or what?

Comment: which version of python? `print` is a function in 3.x. Try using `print(6)`

Comment: Try `print(a)` instead.  Print is a function in 3.x, which may be the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Are you using Python 3? The print function in Python three must use parentheses:

```
a = 6
print(a)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you installed python 3.x on your machine but you are writing python 2.x syntax in it. Try to install python 2.x or use python 3.x syntax while writing.

Answer (score 1):

**You haven't placed brackets in some parts of your code. Which is why Python is screaming at you. Change

```
 a = 6
print a

list = 1, 2, 7, 3
print list
```

to

```
 a = 6
print(a)

list = 1, 2, 7, 3
print(list)
```

Another thing if you're using Python3-x, Python is gonna scream at you. But on Python2-x you needn't put the brackets. From what I understood from the question, you're using Python-3X. Which is why its sending you a syntax error. And I'm pretty sure its nothing because of the Python installation. **

Comment: This doesn't add anything new to existing answers.

Comment: The community encourages adding explanations alongisde code, rather than purely code-based answers (see [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers)).

Comment: Ok sorry about that. Won't make the same mistakes again! I hope my edits are better.